# Single object class (like singleton) with serializing to file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to figure it out myself for almost couple hours now and I can't really get any good idea so I'm asking you, guys!
Problem is I have class "Unit", which contains some public properties. I created class named "UnitList" which is list of many "Unit" objects. Now the problem is I want that "UnitList" be some kind of database for futher usage and I need only one object of that ("UnitList") class and I want it to be serialized to file using standard XmlSerialization class.
Now I have constructor of "UnitList", which should read data from file and transfer it to new "UnitList" object anywhere in all program, but even if xml file is written correctly, I'm getting new, empty object every time I'm declaring it.
How can I achieve that? Or maybe there exist easier way to do it?

EDIT:
Yeah, sure, there is crucial code for my problem. Example of writing to file:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // --- Add ---
    {
        unit = new Unit(textBox1.Text, int.Parse(textBox2.Text), int.Parse(textBox3.Text), int.Parse(textBox4.Text),
                                            int.Parse(textBox5.Text), int.Parse(textBox6.Text), int.Parse(textBox7.Text),
                                            int.Parse(textBox8.Text), int.Parse(textBox9.Text), int.Parse(textBox10.Text), 
                                            int.Parse(textBox11.Text), textBox2.Text);
        unitList.AddUnit(unit);
        XmlSerialization.WriteToXmlFile<UnitList>("List.xml", unitList);
...
```

And my XmlSerialization class:

```
public static class XmlSerialization
{
    public static void WriteToXmlFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, bool append = false) where T : new()
    {
        TextWriter writer = null;
        try
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, append);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, objectToWrite);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (writer != null)
                writer.Close();
        }
    }

    public static T ReadFromXmlFile<T>(string filePath) where T : new()
    {
        TextReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
...
```

EDIT2:

Thanks to Pedro and some "IF" corrections I managed to read xml to my object. Now problem is:

```
Exception:
There is an error in XML document (2, 2).

Inner Exception:
<UnitList xmlns=''> was not expected.
```

I suspect my write funcntion, which saves object "UnitList" to XML file, but in read function I'm reading it as "List". Is this important in this case? Corrected constructor in "UnitList" looks like this:

```
        public UnitList(string file)
    {
        if (File.Exists("List.xml") == false || XmlSerialization.ReadFromXmlFile<List<Unit>>(file) == null)
            unitList = new List<Unit>(500);
        else
            unitList = XmlSerialization.ReadFromXmlFile<List<Unit>>("List.xml");
    }
```

Comment: Maybe some code regarding how you are reading/writing to the file would be helpful.  Do you have this part working yet?

Comment: please provide your code

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to give up XML, I'd suggest you the JSON format. `Newtonsoft.Json` is at the moment one of the most popular .NET JSON libraries.

It's also capable of serializing and deserializing lists with a single line of code, which would make your code cleaner and shorter.

Serialize a list of objects to file:

```
List<Unit> Units = new List<Unit>();
File.WriteAllText(FilePath, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Units));
```

Deserialize from file:

```
List<Unit> Units = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Unit>>(File.ReadAllText(FilePath)).ToList();
```

You should also grab the package:

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

And put a reference to it in your code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Comment: Thank you for easier alternative to XML serialization, but it was a lot of effort to get to the point I'm now and I would like to make it working properly.

Answer (score 0):

This function returns the list that was read from the file:

```
public static T ReadFromXmlFile<T>(string filePath) where T : new()
```

But in your constructor you just call it would setting your variable to the result:

```
XmlSerialization.ReadFromXmlFile<UnitList>("List.xml");
```

You need to set your unitlist value to the result of the call. Your constructor code should look like this:

```
public UnitList(string file)
{
    unitList = XmlSerialization.ReadFromXmlFile<UnitList>("List.xml");
    if (unitList == null) 
        unitList = new List<Unit>(500);
}
```

EDIT:
To handle the type mismatch, rather than reading in the constructor you should do it as a static method that returns the instance of UnitList. And you can use this method in your singleton getter.

```
private static UnitList LoadUnitList()
{
        UnitList result = null;
        if (File.Exists("List.xml") == true)
        {
            result = XmlSerialization.ReadFromXmlFile<UnitList>("List.xml");
        }

        if (result == null) 
            result = new UnitList();

        return result;
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out, additionaly I had to modify that IF statements to cover situations where there is no file or its empty... But there is more troubles... ;]

Comment: You are writing you UnitList class, but reading your internal List<Unit>. That is why there is a type mismatch in your read. You need to also write the internal variable UnitList.unitList. Or, you need a static method that returns the deserialized instance of UnitList.

Comment: Perhaps you can also post your saved xml file, so we can see the format that was saved. Above I'm guessing at what could be the load problem.

Comment: `Error 1 Cannot assign <null> to an implicitly-typed local variable` - It seems like we cannot initialize "result" with null ;]

Comment: Try it with the actual type of UnitList rather than var.